# Are there any tools to help convert latex to katex?

Tags: html

I may be starting a project that will require me to write lots of [katex](https://katex.org/).

I'd prefer to write my code in latex, so I could take advantage of thinks like `tikz` imagez and do calculations with `sagetex`. I'm curious if there any tools available to help translate latex code into katex.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert your latex code to html, but keep math as raw latex, to be rendered by katex?

Comment: You can just compile your document to dvi and then use dvisvgm to produce svg which you can natively embed on the web.

Answer (score 4):

Just made one here: https://latex-katex-converter.vercel.app/

Source code is here if anyone is interested: https://github.com/Zeyu-Li/latex-katex-converter